# Trouble with Numpy C API

Tags: python, numpy, c-api

Code (based on [Numpy C-Api example gives a SegFault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730717/numpy-c-api-example-gives-a-segfault).  The link to the tutorial they were following is dead, and I haven't found a good tutorial):

```c
#include <Python.h>
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_API_VERSION

#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"

int main()
{

   Py_Initialize();
   import_array();

   int typenum;
   PyArrayObject *alpha;
   PyObject *a = NULL;
   int n = 100;
   int nd = 1;
   int dims[nd];
   dims[0] = n;
   a= PyArray_FromDims(nd, dims, NPY_DOUBLE);
   alpha = (PyArrayObject*) a;

   typenum = PyArray_DIMS(alpha)[0];
   printf("%i",typenum);
   PyRun_SimpleString("print 'Hello Python C/API'");
   Py_Finalize();
   return 0;
}
```

```
gcc -g main1.cpp -I/.../include/python2.7 -I/.../numpy/numpy/core/include -lpython2.7 -lstdc++; ./a.out
```

Gives a segfault on `a= PyArray_FromDims(nd, dims, NPY_DOUBLE);`.

I'm in a virtualenvironment, which has ben activated.  The "..." gives the path to my virtual environment where numpy lives as a subdirectory, and has been installed using pip install -e numpy.

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774524/segfault-when-trying-to-write-to-a-numpy-array-created-within-a-c-extension. Another link that might help: https://sourceforge.net/p/numpy/mailman/message/5700519/

Comment: The definition of the macro `import_array()` is `#define import_array() {if (_import_array() < 0) {PyErr_Print(); PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ImportError, "numpy.core.multiarray failed to import"); return NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL; } }`.  So you should check for the return value of `_import_array()` being negative.

Comment: it still doesn't work if I _import_array() to import_array()